# Why I always get "12:00" Value in moment js?

Tags: momentjs

I have an input for time and date. But when I parse time I always get "12:00" value. My code is:

```js
var time = moment($scope.data.time, 'hh:mm').format('hh:mm A');
var date = moment($scope.data.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

//problem starts here when i try to combine each other
var data = date + ' ' + time;

console.log(date); // right value
console.log(time); // right value
console.log(data); // right value of date but wrong time
```

For example my date is `"feb-02-2017"` and my time is `"2:30 pm"`, but the date value will always return `"feb-02-2017 12:00"` whatever the time I input its always return 12:00, can someone help me on this?

Comment: What are values of `$scope.data.time` and `$scope.data.date`?

Comment: date and time value is the same what as what i just formatted above YYYY-MM-DD and hh:mm A

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a snippet showing your issue? It's hard to replicate the problem or give you help only with the info you gave.